# Восстановление запуска Windows 7 после удаления раздела "Зарезервировано системой"

Tags: windows, загрузка

Windows 7 (x64).
Один HDD с тремя разделами (Система, Данные, Зарезервировано Системой).

Удалил раздел Зарезервировано Системой. Он находился между двумя другими разделами и мешал их соединению между собой. Выполнял действия описанные далее, но система не грузится. Получаю ошибки типа: NTLDR is missing, BOOTMGR is missing, Windows failed to start, черный экран с курсором, а также зависания на логотипе Windows.

Делал следующее:

- Воссоздал раздел в 110МБ в хвосте дискового пространства.
- Отформатировал в NTFS. Сделал раздел активным. Задал букву C.
- bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr
- bcdboot D:\windows /s C: (D - раздел c Windows)
- Перезапустил - зависает на логотипе Starting Windows
- Пробовал copy bootmgr C:\ - access denied
- bootrec.exe /fixmbr и bootrec.exe /fixboot - не помогло
- сделал chkdsk /f /r /x всех разделов - не помогло

Диск новый, и до удаления раздела все летало.
Посоветуйте, что еще можно сделать?

Сами разделы в порядке - доступ к файлам обоих разделов есть, не могу только сделать чтобы система запускалась.

Comment: Теперь точно можно смело переставлять систему.

Comment: Если создавали диск восстановления системы - грузитесь с него, если нет - ставьте Windows заново, если предложит обновление системы, можете подумать, а можете ставить с нуля :) Не забудьте сделать бэкап важных файлов.

Comment: А в чем именно криминал? Почему нельзя восстановить такой раздел, я читал что это делается на раз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам не верю, но после двух дней мучений получилось восстановить загрузку.
В последний момент, когда уже перепробовал кучу всего, а именно:

[Лечение BOOTMGR is missing](https://remontcompa.ru/page,1,2,201-bootmgr-is-missing-v-windows-7.html)

[Лечение NTLDR is missing](https://remontcompa.ru/421-ntldr-is-missing-v-windows-7.html)

[Восстановление загрузчика Windows](https://remontcompa.ru/208-vosstanovlenie-zagruzchika-windows-7.html)

Набрел на вот такую ссылку:

[Windows 7 без раздела Зарезервировано системой, восстановление загрузки](https://korsar182.wordpress.com/windows-7-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC/)

(ВНИМАНИЕ - АКТИВАЦИЯ WINDOWS ПРИ ЭТОМ СЛЕТАЕТ)

Удалил раздел Зарезервировано Системой, который пытался воссоздавать своими силами, и сделал то что просили. Вообщем-то, в том или ином порядке я уже выполнял такие же действия ранее, так что надежды было мало, тем более что результатом выполнения bootrec /rebuildbcd снова было - access denied. Но я все же доделал до конца и удалил тот самый файл в конце, возможно именно это и дало положительный эффект.

На всякий случай вот сами действия, если что-то непонятно в них, смотрите ссылки выше подробнее:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
diskpart > select disk 0 > select partition 1 > active
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /rebuildbcd # Отвечаем - Y
copy d:\bootmgr c: #  копируем с установочного диска загрузочную область
del c:\windows\system32\drivers\oem-drv64.sys # удаляем файлик, на который ругается
```

Comment: У вас активация винды не слетела при этом?

Comment: Слетела, но это проблема решается за минуту.
Куда страшнее для меня была бы необходимость переустановки системы